# unnecessary CVT instructions in PTX binary generated from OpenCL

Tags: performance, opencl, nvidia, ptx

I have written a really simple OpenCL code, and tried to execute it on a Tesla K40m GPU and measure the GFlops. Here is the code I've written:

```
__kernel void test(__global float *GIn, __global float *GOut, int M, int N, int P) {
    int X = get_global_id(0);
    // Just a private variable
    float temp = 1.0;


    // Start of a new level of for loop
    int baseIndex1 = (X) * 512;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 0] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 1] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 2] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 3] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 4] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 5] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 6] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 7] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 8] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 9] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 10] * var;
    ...
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 510] * var;
    temp += GIn[baseIndex1 + 511] * var;
    GOut[baseIndex1] = temp;
}
```

I have deployed this kernel on my GPU with global_work_size of [1048576] and local_work_size of [128]. The total number of floating point operations it can performance per second is around 1.6 GFlops, which is extremely low. I assume I'm just doing single operations and also memory is being read sequentially. I've decided to take a look at the generated PTX code:

```
.version 5.0
.target sm_35, texmode_independent
.address_size 64

    // .globl   test
.func  (.param .b64 func_retval0) get_global_id
(
    .param .b32 get_global_id_param_0
)
;

.entry test(
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 4 test_param_0,
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 4 test_param_1,
    .param .u32 test_param_2,
    .param .u32 test_param_3,
    .param .u32 test_param_4
)
{
    .reg .f32   %f<1537>;
    .reg .b32   %r<515>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<1543>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [test_param_0];
    ld.param.u64    %rd2, [test_param_1];
    mov.u32     %r1, 0;
    // Callseq Start 0
    {
    .reg .b32 temp_param_reg;
    // <end>}
    .param .b32 param0;
    st.param.b32    [param0+0], %r1;
    .param .b64 retval0;
    call.uni (retval0), 
    get_global_id, 
    (
    param0
    );
    ld.param.b64    %rd3, [retval0+0];

    //{
    }// Callseq End 0
    cvt.u32.u64 %r2, %rd3;
    mul.lo.s32  %r3, %r2, 512;
    cvt.s64.s32 %rd4, %r3;
    shl.b64     %rd5, %rd4, 2;
    add.s64     %rd6, %rd1, %rd5;
    ld.global.f32   %f1, [%rd6];
    mul.f32     %f2, %f1, 0f3FC00000;
    add.f32     %f3, %f2, 0f3F800000;
    add.s32     %r4, %r3, 1;
    cvt.s64.s32 %rd7, %r4;
    shl.b64     %rd8, %rd7, 2;
    add.s64     %rd9, %rd1, %rd8;
    ld.global.f32   %f4, [%rd9];
    mul.f32     %f5, %f4, 0f3FC00000;
    add.f32     %f6, %f3, %f5;
    add.s32     %r5, %r3, 2;
    cvt.s64.s32 %rd10, %r5;
    shl.b64     %rd11, %rd10, 2;
    add.s64     %rd12, %rd1, %rd11;
    ld.global.f32   %f7, [%rd12];
    mul.f32     %f8, %f7, 0f3FC00000;
    add.f32     %f9, %f6, %f8;
    add.s32     %r6, %r3, 3;
    cvt.s64.s32 %rd13, %r6;
    shl.b64     %rd14, %rd13, 2;
    add.s64     %rd15, %rd1, %rd14;
    ld.global.f32   %f10, [%rd15];
    mul.f32     %f11, %f10, 0f3FC00000;
    add.f32     %f12, %f9, %f11;
    add.s32     %r7, %r3, 4;
    cvt.s64.s32 %rd16, %r7;
    shl.b64     %rd17, %rd16, 2;
    add.s64     %rd18, %rd1, %rd17;
    ld.global.f32   %f13, [%rd18];
    mul.f32     %f14, %f13, 0f3FC00000;
    add.f32     %f15, %f12, %f14;
    add.s32     %r8, %r3, 5;
    cvt.s64.s32 %rd19, %r8;
    shl.b64     %rd20, %rd19, 2;
    add.s64     %rd21, %rd1, %rd20;
    ld.global.f32   %f16, [%rd21];
    mul.f32     %f17, %f16, 0f3FC00000;
    add.f32     %f18, %f15, %f17;
```

As it's clear inside the code, I have unnecessary **cvt** and **shl** instructions, which I assume are one potential cause of overhead.

Now I have two questions here: (1) How should I rewrite my kernel to get rid of two mentioned instructions and make the kernel performs faster? (2) Is there any other source of overhead in my code, which I'm unaware of?

Comment: You are memory-bound, so FLOPS will suffer. You need to coalesce global memory accesses to get full memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

İf var is double type,  that could be convert instruction source as float cant add it directly .

Using same temp for adding everything is a pipeline stopper.

Accessing array with a stride of 512 floats could use only 1 memory Channel and even only 1 memory bank at a time. This May serialize the memory operations on top of already serialized instructions per thread.

Do the reduction between far items, not neighbors and only Pairs or maybe 4 items per thread to solve memory problem.

Use multiple temps for pipeline problem.

Put f postfix for floats if they are not meant for doubles. Try to evade adding double and float repeatedly.

Using a different memory Channel per thread is good.

Letting compiler/hardware rename some registers is good.

Adding less number of values on same register means less probability for round off error Being bigger than added value which is good.

Shifting seems to be adress calculation for float as length of 4. Shifting left by 2 to get adr. Maybe buffer is not aligned? Compute base index plus pointer then add other values instead of recalculating base and its additions at each line which makes slow. Maybe gin parameter needs restrict or const keyword  before entering automatic optimization considerations.

Comment: Thanks much @huseyin for the tips. I will take them into consideration.